# Why does the path based similarity or any similarity for that matter in wordnet give a nan for some senses?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

For example take the two senses `Synset('mile.n.03')` and `Synset('support.v.09)` when i compute the path based similarity between these two senses as follows

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn  
mile = wn.synset('mile.n.03')  
support = wn.synset('support.v.09')
support2 = wn.synset('documentation.n.03')
wn.path_similarity(mile,support)    #no output
wn.path_similarity(mile,support2)   #get an output 0.08333
```

Any idea why is this happening? Or is there some fundamental mistake i am making?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the docs for [path_similarity](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet-module.html#path_similarity):

> A score denoting the similarity of the two Synsets, normally between 0 and 1. **None** is returned if no connecting path could be found...(will only be true for verbs as there are many distinct verb taxonomies).

So, it seems no connecting path is found, as `support` is a verb.

Comment: More fundamentally, noun and verb taxonomies are distinct in WordNet, so there is no path from any noun to any verb.

Comment: @fraxel thanks for the answer. i too have realized this. made the change in my code to take care of this situation.